# Select objects based on size

Tags: scripting, objects, selection-tools

I am generating rubble with cell fracture. This means I have hundreds of objects. For various reasons, I want to select all of the larger pieces. Is there a way to select all objects above a certain size, or deselect all below a certain size?

Scripts are good too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

This script will select all the objects that have a similar volume to the selected object (by similar I mean the same rough scale - tens, hundreds, thousands, etc):

```
import bpy, bmesh

bm = bmesh.new()
bm.from_mesh( bpy.context.object.data )

ref_obj_name     = bpy.context.object.name
reference_volume = float( bm.calc_volume() )
ref_vol_scale    = ( '%.0E' % reference_volume )[-3:]

# Select all the objects in the scene that have a similar volume (of the same scale)
for o in [ m for m in bpy.context.scene.objects if m.type == 'MESH' ]:
    if o.name == ref_obj_name: continue

    bm = bmesh.new()
    bm.from_mesh( o.data )

    vol       = float( bm.calc_volume() )
    vol_scale = ( '%.0E' % vol )[-3:]

    if vol_scale == ref_vol_scale:
        o.select = True
```

Comment: Works also in blender 2.8. Just change the last line to: o.select_set(True) Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for the script. Is it possible to make it more accurate and add things like bounding box parameters, maybe?